# Issue while converting array from one format to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have the following input array(It's a Javascript Object[] Array response):

```
[
    {index:1, headerCSV:"Name", dataFields: ["Name", "Id"]},
    {index:2, headerCSV:"Id", dataFields: ["Test", "Test 1"]},
    {index:3, headerCSV:"fname", dataFields: ["Test", "Test 1"]},
    {index:4, headerCSV:"lname", dataFields: []},
]
```

I am trying to convert it to the following array:

```
[
    {"header" : 1, "field" :"Name"},
    {"header" : 1, "field" :"Id"},
    {"header" : 2, "field" :"Test"},
    {"header" : 2, "field" :"Test 1"},
    {"header" : 3, "field" :"Test"},
    {"header" : 3, "field" :"Test 1"}
]
```

In the result array I'll need to put in the `header` with the input array `index` and in the `field` I'll need to construct using the array of the `dataFields` array of the input array. I have tried with the following code:

```
var CSVHeadersAndFields = /* The input array */;
var headerFieldMappingJSON = [];
for(var i=0; i<CSVHeadersAndFields.length;i++) {
    headerFieldMappingJSON[i] = {};
    var selectedFields = CSVHeadersAndFields[i].dataFields;
    for(var j=0; j<selectedFields.length;j++) {
        headerFieldMappingJSON[i].header = CSVHeadersAndFields[i].index;
        headerFieldMappingJSON[i].field = selectedFields[j];
    }
}
```

But I have got the following result:

```
[
    {"header":1,"field":"Name"},
    {"header":2,"field":"Test"},
    {"header":3,"field":"Test"},
    {}
]
```

I suspect form the for loop 1st iteration value is replaced by the second iteration and also I'll need to avoid to construct the output array mapping from the empty array of `dataFields` from the input array.

How to make a correct algorithm to convert the array?

Comment: Can you post the actual array response, in JSON/object literal format, and not, eg, `dataFields:Array(2)`, so that your situation can be reproduced?

Comment: 0:{index: 0, headerCSV: "Id", dataImportFields: Array(2), dataImportFieldsStr: "Id,Name", isMap: false}
1:{index: 1, headerCSV: "Name", dataImportFields: Array(0), dataImportFieldsStr: "", isMap: true}
2:{index: 2, headerCSV: "FirstName", dataImportFields: Array(2), dataImportFieldsStr: "Id,Name", isMap: false}
3:{index: 3, headerCSV: "LastName", dataImportFields: Array(0), dataImportFieldsStr: "", isMap: true}

Comment: You still have those `Array(2)`s everywhere...

Comment: If you could show what you expect the output of `fields` to be for one of the rows it would help.

Comment: Actual response is already there in the question and the dataFields.Array[2] also in the question.

Comment: It needs to be `[i+j]` inside of `headerFieldMappingJSON[i+j].header`. This is also where you should init your object. `headerFieldMappingJSON[i+j] = {};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a separate iterator index for the result array. Or just push to the result array instead of adding values by index:

```
var CSVHeadersAndFields = /* The array from question */;
var headerFieldMappingJSON = [];
for(var i = 0; i < CSVHeadersAndFields.length; i++) {
    var selectedFields = CSVHeadersAndFields[i].dataFields;
    for(var j = 0; j < selectedFields.length; j++) {
        headerFieldMappingJSON.push({
            header: CSVHeadersAndFields[i].index,
            field: selectedFields[j]
        });
    }
}
```

The same example but cleaner:

```
var input = /* The array from question */;
var output = [];

input.forEach(function (csvRow) {
    csvRow.dataFields.forEach(function (field) {
        output.push({
            header: csvRow.index,
            field: field
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below will give you one result object per `dataField` and use the `index` property from `CSVHeadersAndFields` as the `header` property for each of them.

`const result = CSVHeadersAndFields.map(item =>
  item.dataFields.map(field => {
    return {
      header: item.index,
      field
    }
  })
);`

Comment: I don't think it does what the author wants. He needs to convert the response value to the header-field value.

Comment: Oh hold on, I see!

Answer (score 1):

You can try following approach:

#### Logic:

- Loop over data and push data in an array based on parsing logic.
- In every iteration, you can again loop over `obj.dataFields` and create object for every field.
- You can then merge this output array to original output list.

```js
var data = [
  {index:1, headerCSV:"Name", dataFields: ["Name", "Id"] },
  {index:2, headerCSV:"Id", dataFields: ["Test", "Test 1"] },
  {index:3, headerCSV:"fname", dataFields: ["Test", "Test 1"] },
  {index:4, headerCSV:"lname", dataFields: []}
];

var output = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const header = obj.index;
  return acc.concat( obj.dataFields.map((field) => ({ header, field}) ))
}, []);

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the simpler code:

```
    var CSVHeadersAndFields = [ {index:1, headerCSV:"Name", dataFields: ["Name","Id"]},
     {index:2, headerCSV:"Id", dataFields:["Test","Test 1"]},{index:3, headerCSV:"fname", dataFields:["Test","Test 1"]}, {index:4, headerCSV:"lname", dataFields:[]};

    var headerFieldMappingJSON  = [];

   for(var CSVHeadersAndField of CSVHeadersAndFields ) {
       for(var dataFieldVal of CSVHeadersAndField['dataFields']){
         headerFieldMappingJSON.push({'header': CSVHeadersAndField['index'], 'field': dataFieldVal })
       }
   }
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "header": 1,
    "field": "Name"
  },
  {
    "header": 1,
    "field": "Id"
  },
  {
    "header": 2,
    "field": "Test"
  },
  {
    "header": 2,
    "field": "Test 1"
  },
  {
    "header": 3,
    "field": "Test"
  },
  {
    "header": 3,
    "field": "Test 1"
  }
]
```

Comment: I got the following Exception, Uncaught Action failed: Header_Field_Mapping$controller$handleNext [CSVHeadersAndField.dataFields is not iterable]

Comment: I ran it in my machine and pasted the code here, there is no exception nor error, Which language are you using ?

Comment: Anyways that error is because you might have changed the 'dataFields' type, it should be an array to iterate, which is the case in this example you have posted.

Comment: I didn't change the data type and it's still as Array.